# Load download in browser background, tell when finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I'm trying to get a file which takes a good few seconds to load in the background, so I can display a spinner at the same time.

I'm currently trying with an iframe in the background, and this works but I'm not sure how I can be notified when it's finished loading (so I can remove the spinner).

Any good ways of doing this? Any better solution than an iframe?

Here's my code so far:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var link = $('.generate-pdf');

        link.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var spinner = $("<img src='/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
            var iframe = $('<iframe src="' + link.attr('href') + '" style="height:0;width:0;visibility;hidden;display:none;"></iframe>');
            link.before(spinner);
            link.before(iframe);

        });
    })
</script>
```

According to [this site](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2009/06/18/events-to-expect-when-dynamically-loading-iframes-in-javascript.aspx), given that my `Content-disposition` is `attachment` I can't guarantee to receive any events. Can I poll any properties on the iframe to find out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
iframe.load(function(){
    log("done");
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I had no joy with that - On Chrome at least.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to do this by contacting the server, and seeing if the file had been sent to the browser. I'd still like to see a pure client-based implementation.

Thankfully the download was generated with PHP so this was ok.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var link = $('.generate-pdf');

        link.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var spinner = $("<div class='spinner'><img src='/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif' /><span>Your PDF is being generated...</span></div>");
            var downloadKey = new Date().getTime();
            var iframe = $('<iframe src="' + link.attr('href') + '&downloadKey='+downloadKey+'" style="height:0;width:0;visibility;hidden;display:none;" onload="alert(\'hello\')"></iframe>');
            link.before(spinner);
            link.before(iframe);

            var hasFinished = function(downloadKey, callback) {
                var that = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "index.php?controller=is-download-finished&downloadKey=" + downloadKey,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data) {
                            callback();
                        } else {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                that(downloadKey, callback);
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                })
            };
            hasFinished(downloadKey, function() {
                spinner.remove();
                iframe.remove();
            });

        });
    })
</script>
```

The extra request just returns JSON true or false.